# Pandas use groupby to apply a different function for each value of the groupby variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to use groupby, but instead of applying the same functions to each group, I want to specify which function to apply to which group value.  I'm providing a very simple example here to illustrate the point, but in reality there are many values of my groupby variable, and my functions are all user-defined and fairly complex -- so solutions that involve selecting each group separately or apply the same functions to all groups will not be practical.  (Answers of that sort were provided to this very similar question: [how to apply different functions to each group of pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130769/how-to-apply-different-functions-to-each-group-of-pandas-groupby) but they don't address my question)

```
df = DataFrame({'Category': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
               'Total': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
```

I'd like to be able to specify a function for each level of my groupby variable:

```
function_map = {'A': np.mean,
                'B': np.max,
                'C': np.min}
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(function_map)
```

And the form of result I want would look like this DataFrame:

```
result = DataFrame({'Category': ['A','B','C'],
               'Total': [2, 3, 1]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a lambda, something like this

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda r: function_map[r.name](r.Total))
```

also, you should use `numpy` functions so `np.mean`, `np.max`, `np.min`

Comment: This makes sense, but how do I specify function_map so that it contains functions in valid python syntax?  Or, alternatively, if I store the names of the functions as strings, how do I then pass them as functions to apply?

Comment: I edited my question to use numpy functions as you suggested, which allows me to create a valid dict for function_map.  When I try to use your approach now, I get an error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: try `r.Category.iloc[0]` so that you're not passing the whole series.

Comment: Now it works, thanks!  This also seems to work: `df.groupby('Category').Total.apply(lambda r: function_map[r.name](r))`

Comment: yes, `r.name` is even better! i will update my answer.